# Showing $\int_a^{a+h} |x-x_0| \le \dfrac{1}{2} h^2$ for $x_0\in [a,a+h]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to show that if $x_0 \in [a,a+h]$ where $h \gt 0$ then

$\int_a^{a+h}|x-x_0|dx \le \dfrac{1}{2}h^2$.

So if $|x-x_0| \le |x-a|$ then this is easy, as $\int_a^{a+h}|x-a|dx = \dfrac{1}{2}h^2$.

My problem is that this condition only holds in $[(x_0+a)/2,a+h]$.

Does someone see a way around this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you are given the function and it is easy to integrate by breaking into parts, I don't see why you want to use the mean value theorem, which would give the condition holding in the interval you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\int_a^{a+h}|x-x_0|dx = \int_a^{x_0}(x_0-x)dx  + \int_{x_0}^{a+h}(x-x_0)dx \\
= \int_0^{x_0-a} x \, dx + \int_0^{a+h-x_0} x\,dx \\
= \frac 12 (x_0-a)^2 + \frac 12 (a+h-x_0)^2
$$
This is a convex function of $x_0$ (a parabola) so that the maximum is attained at the boundary of the interval, i.e. for $x_0 = a$ or $x_0 = a+h$.

---

Or, with (almost) no calculation: For every fixed $x \in [a, a+h]$ is
$$
 y \mapsto |x -y |
$$
a convex function of $y$. It follows that
$$
 f(y) = \int_a^{a+h} |x-y| \, dx
$$
is a convex function, and therefore
$$
 \max_{y \in [a,a+h]} f(y) = \max(f(a), f(a+h)) = f(a)
$$
because of the symmetry. So $f(a) = \frac 12 h^2$ is the maximal value.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the given integral is $\int_a^{x_0} (x_0-x)dx+\int_{x_0}^{a+h} (x-x_0)dx$.

After evaluating the integral explicitly just use the fact that $x_0 \in [a,a+h]$ and you will get the bound easily.